# iOS Kiwi test case with error passed via reference

Tags: ios, unit-testing, pass-by-reference, kiwi

let's say we have:

```
 - (NSString *)someMethod:(NSString *)input
 {
      NSError *error = nil;
      NSString *result = [otherObject processInput:input error:&error];

      if (error == nil) {
           return result;
      }
      else {
           return nil;
      }
 }
```

How can I unit test it using Kiwi to check how else is behaving?

Of course I could put something nasty as `input`  but I don't want to use that approach. It's unit test for `someMethod:` method, not for `processInput:error:` method and `otherObject` is a `KWMock`. I've been trying to use `KWCaptureSpy` class, or `stub: withArguments:` but either I've used them wrong or they are not the solution.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cocoa you should check if a method returns `nil`, not check `error` against `nil`: http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/260201639/nserror-is-hard.

So maybe rewrite `someMethod` to check value returned by `otherObject` stub, not the `error` pointer. It will be easier to test that way (you only have to call `stub:andReturn:` method from `KWMock`, returning either `nil` or a non-nil value) and you will follow Cococa conventions.